# Sum values of points within polygon R

Tags: r

I want to sum the values of points within each polygon in R, but not exactly sure how to do it. I have computed counts of points, but not a summarization of values of the points within each polygon.

I am also not sure how to generate toy code; sorry for the lack of an example.

Comment: This is a legit and perfectly clear question, and the desired behavior is well described (sum the values of points within each polygon, very little ambiguity there, if any). Obviously it would be better if some example data were provided but the OP states that they do not have the capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with `terra`

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
set.seed(3241)
p <- spatSample(v, 100)
values(p) <- data.frame(val=1:nrow(p))
plot(v)
points(p)
```

Solution

```
r <- relate(v, p, "intersects")
a <- apply(r, 1, function(i) sum(p$val[i]))
a
# [1]  113  219  683  132  395  359  287  354  308  628 1099  473
```

Perhaps followed by

```
v$psum <- a
```

If you need to coerce from and to `sf` (which has similar functionality for vector data)

```
sf <- sf::st_as_sf(v)
vv <- vect(sf)
```

Or from and to `sp`

```
sp <- as(v, "Spatial")
vvv <- vect(sp)
```